# configure log4javascript to struts web application

Tags: javascript, struts, log4j, log4javascript

How can we write the JavaScript info and error messages to the log file using log4j.

Please find the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="././scripts/log4javascript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var log = log4javascript.getDefaultLogger();
    log.removeAllAppenders();
    log.addAppender("start logging");
</script>
function writetoLog()
    {
        log.info("Start the Script Log..");
    }
<body onload="writetoLog();">Some html code here </body>
```

This info messages is not write to the my log file.

Please suggest

Comment: Maybe a typo, but your function must be inside a script tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an `AjaxAppender`. It's covered in the documentation of log4javascript (for example, in the quick start tutorial: http://log4javascript.org/docs/quickstart.html).

```
var log = log4javascript.getLogger("server");
var ajaxAppender = new log4javascript.AjaxAppender("/yourapp/jslog.do");
log.addAppender(ajaxAppender);

log.debug("Testing server log");
```

Comment: what will we write in jslog.do action class?

Comment: @Chandrasekhar: You'll need to extract logging information from the HTTP post data and log it using log4j. The default parameters sent by `AjaxAppender` are "logger", "timestamp", "milliseconds", "level", "message", "exception" and "url".

Comment: Thanks for giving response.Can you give the sample action class code?